# Change and update the size of the cursor in Windows 10 via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, winapi

I've written the code below to affect (what I think)  are the only reg keys responsible for the size of the cursor and pointer in Windows 10.

Here's the code I have so far (Some additional comments within):

```
$RegConnect             = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"CurrentUser", "$env:COMPUTERNAME")
$RegCursorsAccess       = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Accessibility", $true)
$RegCursorsControlPanel = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Cursors", $true)

# In the code below I'm trying to change the size of the cursor.

$RegCursorsControlPanel.SetValue("CursorBaseSize", 48)
$RegCursorsAccess.SetValue("CursorSize", 3)

$RegCursorsAccess.Close()
$RegConnect.Close()

# This section is where I thought it would update the cursor size.

# Here is where it lists stuff relating to setting and updating any settings changed.
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa
    # SPI_SETCURSORS
    # 0x0057
    # Reloads the system cursors. Set the uiParam parameter to zero and the pvParam parameter to NULL.

$CSharpSig = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                  uint uiAction,
                  uint uiParam,
                  uint pvParam,
                  uint fWinIni);
'@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo -PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
```

---

It will change the correct values in the registry.

So if I run this PowerShell code the mouse size in the ease of access setting is at the correct value.

[image: cursor and pointer size setting]

But the cursor doesn't update.

How is it possible to force the update without logging out and back in or restarting the machine.

---

**Here are some related MS links:**

[WM_SETTINGCHANGE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange)

[SystemParametersInfoA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa)

---

### EDIT - Some additional info

If I run [Process Monitor from Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and dig deep in there I can see this under the stack summary.

This may lead someone more knowledgeable than me to find how to update the mouse size.

The **`HKCU\Control Panel\Cursors\(Default)`** section **`SettingsHandlers_nt.dll`**

[image: Sysinternals Process Monitor]

And this also for the accessibility section. **`Windows.UI.Accessibility.dll`**

[image: Windows.UI.Accessibility.dll]

Here are the settings I used in Process Monitors filter to narrow down the items.

[image: Settings used as the filter]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after a bit of hacking about SystemSettings.exe with cheat engine I found how MS sets the cursor size. It ends up still using SystemParametersInfo but with some undocumented arguments. Try the following :)

```
SystemParametersInfo(0x2029, 0, 16, 0x01);
```

to set a cursor size of 16. yup you can go below their minimum of 32, all the way down to 1 :)

Comment: Thanks very much this works. Do you know why the UI doesn't update in this image? It only updates after a restart. https://i.imgur.com/0wJI8Ww.png

Comment: that tool sets multiple registry entries and reads from
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Accessibility\CursorSize
which uses 1-15 size format. 

while SystemParametersInfo with 0x2029 is just
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors\CursorBaseSize

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to check which ones are changed when that slider is moved?

Comment: @Ste just handle WM_SETTINGCHANGE in your app and re-read registry values.

Comment: Thanks @DJm00n but if you mean update the cursor then that's solved. Or do you mean updating the window UI size?

Comment: @Ste I meant that you can handle it to have notification when cursor settings was changed in Windows. after this you can recreate your cursors with proper size.

Comment: I see, feel free to add an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> But the cursor doesn't update.

After registry value changed, **it requires trigger to apply these update**.

**It can be done using [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa?redirectedfrom=MSDN#parameters) function with `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` and `SPIF_SENDCHANGE`** **to writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile and broadcasts the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message after updating the user profile.**

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

The following is a PowerShell command example:

```
$RegConnect = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"CurrentUser","$env:COMPUTERNAME")


$RegCursors = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Cursors",$true)


$RegCursors.SetValue("","Windows Black")
$RegCursors.SetValue("CursorBaseSize",0x40)

$RegCursors.SetValue("AppStarting","%SystemRoot%\cursors\wait_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("Arrow","%SystemRoot%\cursors\arrow_rl.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("Crosshair","%SystemRoot%\cursors\cross_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("Hand","")

$RegCursors.SetValue("Help","%SystemRoot%\cursors\help_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("IBeam","%SystemRoot%\cursors\beam_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("No","%SystemRoot%\cursors\no_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("NWPen","%SystemRoot%\cursors\pen_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("SizeAll","%SystemRoot%\cursors\move_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("SizeNESW","%SystemRoot%\cursors\size1_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("SizeNS","%SystemRoot%\cursors\size4_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("SizeNWSE","%SystemRoot%\cursors\size2_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("SizeWE","%SystemRoot%\cursors\size3_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("UpArrow","%SystemRoot%\cursors\up_r.cur")

$RegCursors.SetValue("Wait","%SystemRoot%\cursors\busy_r.cur")

$RegCursors.Close()

$RegConnect.Close()


function Update-UserPreferencesMask {
$Signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);

const int SPI_SETCURSORS = 0x0057;
const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

public static void UpdateUserPreferencesMask() {
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
}
"@
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name UserPreferencesMaskSPI -Namespace User32
    [User32.UserPreferencesMaskSPI]::UpdateUserPreferencesMask()
}
Update-UserPreferencesMask
```

But unfortunately, the cursor size update doesn't work in this way.

A workaround is using arrow_rl.cur (large image) instead of arrow_r.cur.

Refer to [Use PowerShell to Change the Mouse Pointer Scheme](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/), [Programmatically change custom mouse cursor in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713827/programmatically-change-custom-mouse-cursor-in-windows).

Comment: Thanks. This is why I was trying to change the registry item of both values which are interlinked. The `CursorSize` and `CusorBaseSize`. Unfortunately, this workaround isn't what I was after. I wanted to control it like how the access setting does, only to keep the existing style. But this part is beyond the scope of the question. If I can set the size then the other won't be as difficult.

Comment: @Ste If edit size and color from system setting is ok for you, you can consider [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure. If you're not aware when you set a certain style as your cursor and you change the size, the style is lost. I can change the style but I wanted to chage the size while keeping the existing scheme. My end goal here is to export a `.reg` file of the existing scheme, change the cursor size (while not restarting) and then reimport the `.reg` file back in again. This is the only workaround I can see. But this thread is primarily about setting the size. Have you an example of how this UI automation could work in regards my issue?

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this issue? This AHK script also uses SPI_SETCURSORS (0x57) and it works, but I can't figure out how to use it to change the size of the cursor - https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32608-changing-the-system-cursor/

Comment: I changed `"Windows Black"` `"Windows Inverted"` and set the cursors to end with `_i` and it worked for me. Thanks.