# Large Mouse Cursor Icons in virt-manager QEMU/KVM Winows 10 Guest at 4K

Tags: windows-10, mouse, qemu, kvm

Windows 10 with a screen resolution of 3840x2160 scales to 200% perfectly for an installation on bare metal, both fonts and mouse cursor icons resize proportionally.  When scaling to 200% at the same resolution on a virt-manager QEMU/KVM Windows 10 virtual machine the fonts appear correctly but not the mouse pointer icons, these become significantly larger.

Attempted to reduce the mouse cursor icons size using options within Windows settings but these are already set to the smallest size available.  Is there a way to reduce the cursor icons for a Windows 10 guest running within virt-manager QEMU/KVM at 3840x2160/200%?

Answer (score 0):

Modified the Windows registry setting for Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors\CursorBaseSize. Changed from 20 to 10, rebooted and the cursor size is normal, although not clear as the other text.

Solution was found in this post - [Change and update the size of the cursor in Windows 10 via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104778/change-and-update-the-size-of-the-cursor-in-windows-10-via-powershell)